# Cannot convert value of type error - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '((ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink,
>   Event) -> Disposable)!' to expected argument type '(_) ->
>   Disposable'

Below is my code:

```
final fileprivate class ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink < O: ObserverType >: ObserverBase < O.E > {
  let scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler
  let observer: O

  let cancel: Cancelable

  var cachedScheduleLambda: ((ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink < O > , Event < E > ) - > Disposable) !

    init(scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler, observer: O, cancel: Cancelable) {
      self.scheduler = scheduler
      self.observer = observer
      self.cancel = cancel
      super.init()

      cachedScheduleLambda = {
        sink,
        event in
        sink.observer.on(event)

        if event.isStopEvent {
          sink.dispose()
        }

        return Disposables.create()
      }
    }

  override func onCore(_ event: Event < E > ) {
    let _ = self.scheduler.schedule((self, event), action: cachedScheduleLambda) //error
  }

  override func dispose() {
    super.dispose()

    cancel.dispose()
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the method scheduler.shedule API? what kind of value it can retrieve as an argument before the action? I mean you should check the "StateType"